# How can I create "sun like" lines around a circle?

Tags: css, css-shapes

[image: CSS sun shape]

I basically need to create this design in the image. I know it can be achieved with CSS but I'm not sure how to. I've trying Googling it but I can only find elaborate "sun" designs such as this one, which is too much for me to break down for my current understanding.

https://codepen.io/zmmbreeze/pen/guLfC

I've created the center piece like this (using sass):

```
  &__count {
    width: 12rem;
    height: 12rem;
    color: $lightPurple;
    border: $border;
    font-size: 4rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    border-radius: 100%;
    @include centerContent;
  }
```

How can I add the "rays"?

This is what I've tried to extract:

```
.count-down {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  @include centerContent;
  &__count {
    width: 12rem;
    height: 12rem;
    color: $lightPurple;
    border: $border;
    font-size: 4rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    border-radius: 100%;
    @include centerContent;
  }

  &__go {
    width: 15rem;
    height: 15rem;
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid white;
    font-size: 4rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    border-radius: 100%;
    @include centerContent;
  }
}

.sun-light b,
.sun-light s {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 12%; /* 100*30/100=18.75 */
  background: #fed65b;
}
.sun-light s {
  top: auto;
  bottom: 0;
}
.sun-light:nth-child(10n + 2) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(18deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(18deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(18deg);
  -ie-transform: rotate(18deg);
  transform: rotate(18deg);
}
.sun-light:nth-child(10n + 3) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(36deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(36deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(36deg);
  -ie-transform: rotate(36deg);
  transform: rotate(36deg);
}
.sun-light:nth-child(10n + 4) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(54deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(54deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(54deg);
  -ie-transform: rotate(54deg);
  transform: rotate(54deg);
}
.sun-light:nth-child(10n + 5) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(72deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(72deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(72deg);
  -ie-transform: rotate(72deg);
  transform: rotate(72deg);
}
.sun-light:nth-child(10n + 6) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ie-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.sun-light:nth-child(10n + 7) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(108deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(108deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(108deg);
  -ie-transform: rotate(108deg);
  transform: rotate(108deg);
}
.sun-light:nth-child(10n + 8) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(126deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(126deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(126deg);
  -ie-transform: rotate(126deg);
  transform: rotate(126deg);
}
.sun-light:nth-child(10n + 9) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(144deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(144deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(144deg);
  -ie-transform: rotate(144deg);
  transform: rotate(144deg);
}
.sun-light:nth-child(10n + 10) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(162deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(162deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(162deg);
  -ie-transform: rotate(162deg);
  transform: rotate(162deg);
}
```

And this is my component (React.js):

```
<div className="count-down">
  {timeToStart > 1 ? (
    <div className="count-down__count">{Math.floor(timeToStart)}</div>
  ) : (
    <div className="count-down__go">Go!</div>
  )}

  <div class="sun-light">
    <b></b>
    <s></s>
  </div>
  <div class="sun-light">
    <b></b>
    <s></s>
  </div>
  <div class="sun-light">
    <b></b>
    <s></s>
  </div>
  <div class="sun-light">
    <b></b>
    <s></s>
  </div>
  <div class="sun-light">
    <b></b>
    <s></s>
  </div>
  <div class="sun-light">
    <b></b>
    <s></s>
  </div>
  <div class="sun-light">
    <b></b>
    <s></s>
  </div>
  <div class="sun-light">
    <b></b>
    <s></s>
  </div>
  <div class="sun-light">
    <b></b>
    <s></s>
  </div>
  <div class="sun-light">
    <b></b>
    <s></s>
  </div>
  <div class="sun-light">
    <b></b>
    <s></s>
  </div>
  <div class="sun-light">
    <b></b>
    <s></s>
  </div>
</div>
```

But I get this result for some reason:

[image]

Comment: In the [codepen](https://codepen.io/zmmbreeze/pen/guLfC), the sun rays, are created by using `childs` and setting their values accordingly.

Comment: @ElysianStorm I should have added my attempt in my original question. I've tried to take those, but I still don't get the same result. I've set the parent to `position:relative`

Comment: The rays have `position: absolute`, so does the sun ball. The entire sun should be placed in a `container div` that can be set to `position: relative`

Comment: @ElysianStorm unless I'm missing something, I think that that's what 'm doing. The parent is `count-down` and it's set to relative

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try it using `conic-gradient` and `mask` like below

```css
.box {
  --s:20px; /* length */
  --o:10px; /* offset */
  --w:6deg; /* thickness */
  --n:8;    /* numbers*/
  --c:green;/* color */
  
  margin:calc(var(--s) + var(--o) + 10px);
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  display:inline-block;
  border:2px solid red;
  border-radius:50%;
  position:relative;
}
.box::before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:    calc(-1*var(--s) - var(--o));
  bottom: calc(-1*var(--s) - var(--o));
  left:   calc(-1*var(--s) - var(--o));
  right:  calc(-1*var(--s) - var(--o));
  border-radius:inherit;
  background:repeating-conic-gradient(from calc(-1*var(--w)/2), var(--c) 0 calc(var(--w) - 2deg),transparent calc(var(--w)) calc(360deg/var(--n) - 2deg),var(--c) calc(360deg/var(--n)));
  -webkit-mask:radial-gradient(farthest-side,transparent calc(100% - var(--s)),#fff calc(100% - var(--s)));
          mask:radial-gradient(farthest-side,transparent calc(100% - var(--s)),#fff calc(100% - var(--s)));
}

body {
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box" style="--s:30px;--o:5px;--n:10;--c:yellow;--w:4deg"></div>
<div class="box" style="--s:15px;--o:20px;--n:6;--c:blue;--w:10deg"></div>
```

[image: CSS circular sun shape]

For better support you can replace the conic-gradient with multiple linear-gradient but you will have less flexibility to control the number of rays:

```css
.box {
  --s:20px; /* length */
  --o:10px; /* offset */
  --c:green; /* color */
  --w:4px; /* thickness*/
  
  --grad:transparent calc(50% - var(--w)/2), 
        var(--c) calc(50% - var(--w)/2 + 1px) 
                 calc(50% + var(--w)/2 - 1px), 
         transparent calc(50% + var(--w)/2);
  
  margin:calc(var(--s) + var(--o) + 10px);
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  display:inline-block;
  border:2px solid red;
  border-radius:50%;
  position:relative;
}
.box::before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:    calc(-1*var(--s) - var(--o));
  bottom: calc(-1*var(--s) - var(--o));
  left:   calc(-1*var(--s) - var(--o));
  right:  calc(-1*var(--s) - var(--o));
  border-radius:inherit;
  background:
    /* 8 rays */
    linear-gradient(0deg   ,var(--grad)),
    linear-gradient(45deg  ,var(--grad)),
    linear-gradient(-45deg ,var(--grad)),
    linear-gradient(90deg  ,var(--grad));
    /* */
  -webkit-mask:radial-gradient(farthest-side,transparent calc(100% - var(--s)),#fff calc(100% - var(--s)));
          mask:radial-gradient(farthest-side,transparent calc(100% - var(--s)),#fff calc(100% - var(--s)));
}

body {
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box" style="--s:30px;--o:5px;--c:yellow;--w:8px"></div>
<div class="box" style="--s:15px;--o:20px;--c:blue;--w:10px"></div>
```

[image: CSS linear-gradient sun shape]

And if you want to consider border-radius for the ray here is an idea with SVG. Here  you will need to adjust manually the SVG each time you want to have a different color, thickness or radius:

```css
.box {
  --s:20px; /* length */
  --o:10px; /* offset */
  
  --grad:transparent calc(50% - var(--w)/2), 
        var(--c) calc(50% - var(--w)/2 + 1px) 
                 calc(50% + var(--w)/2 - 1px), 
         transparent calc(50% + var(--w)/2);
  
  margin:calc(var(--s) + var(--o) + 10px);
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  display:inline-block;
  border:2px solid red;
  border-radius:50%;
  position:relative;
}
.box::before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:    calc(-1*var(--s) - var(--o));
  bottom: calc(-1*var(--s) - var(--o));
  left:   calc(-1*var(--s) - var(--o));
  right:  calc(-1*var(--s) - var(--o));
  border-radius:inherit;
  background:
    /* 8 rays */
    url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 256 256' width='256' style='transform:rotate(0deg);'> <rect x='118' y='0' width='20' height='100%' rx='10' ry='10' fill='green' /></svg>"),
    url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 256 256' width='256' style='transform:rotate(45deg);'> <rect x='118' y='0' width='20' height='100%' rx='10' ry='10' fill='green' /></svg>"),
    url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 256 256' width='256' style='transform:rotate(-45deg);'> <rect x='118' y='0' width='20' height='100%' rx='10' ry='10' fill='green' /></svg>"),
    url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 256 256' width='256' style='transform:rotate(90deg);'> <rect x='118' y='0' width='20' height='100%' rx='10' ry='10' fill='green' /></svg>");
    /* */
  background-size:100% 100%;
  -webkit-mask:radial-gradient(farthest-side,transparent calc(100% - var(--s)),#fff calc(100% - var(--s)));
          mask:radial-gradient(farthest-side,transparent calc(100% - var(--s)),#fff calc(100% - var(--s)));
}

body {
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box" style="--s:30px;--o:5px;"></div>
<div class="box" style="--s:15px;--o:20px;"></div>
```

[image: SVG background sun like circle]

---

A final idea without mask, SVG and complex gradient but many elements:

```css
.box {
  --s:20px; /* length */
  --o:10px; /* offset */
  --w:6px; /* thickness */
  --c:green;/* color */
  
  margin:calc(var(--s) + var(--o) + 10px);
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  display:inline-block;
  border:2px solid red;
  border-radius:50%;
  position:relative;
}
.box span{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  width:var(--w);
  left:50%;
  top:    calc(-1*var(--s) - var(--o));
  bottom: calc(-1*var(--s) - var(--o));
  border-radius:5px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(var(--c),var(--c)) top,
    linear-gradient(var(--c),var(--c)) bottom;
  background-size:100% var(--s);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  transform:translate(-50%) rotate(var(--r,0deg));
}

.box span:nth-child(2) { --r:45deg; }
.box span:nth-child(3) { --r:-45deg; }
.box span:nth-child(4) { --r:90deg; }

body {
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
</div>

<div class="box" style="--s:30px;--o:5px;--c:yellow;--w:4px">
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
</div>

<div class="box" style="--s:15px;--o:20px;--c:blue;--w:10px">
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
</div>
```

[image: Sun like CSS shapes]

Comment: This answer is too innovative and optimized. It deserves to be accepted. Cheers :)

Comment: Just got back to my computer. Accepted the answer. Thank you both!

Answer (score 1):

In the [codepen](https://codepen.io/zmmbreeze/pen/guLfC) the rays are created by using multiple `div's` that have `position: absolute` and are rotated using the `transform:rotate()` property.

This can all be placed in a `container div` which can have `position: relative` for ease of deployment.

You also were missing

```
.sun-light {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    width: 5px;
    height: 60%;    /*For Radius Variation*/
}
```

Applying all those, I have created a simple snippet:

```css
.container{
    height: 600px;    /* Vary this for changing the size of the entire sun WRT the container */
    position: relative;
    background: grey;
}

.container_go {
    width: 15rem;    /*Would be recommended to provide a unit relative to div*/
    height: 15rem;
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid white;
    font-size: 4rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    border-radius: 100%;

    /* Added CSS */
    position: absolute;
    top: 12%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    /* For aligning text in center */
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 15rem;
}

.sun-light {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    width: 5px;
    height: 60%;    /*For Radius Variation*/
}

/* For design of rays*/
.sun-light b,
.sun-light s {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 12%;    /* 100*30/100=18.75 */
    background: #fed65b;
}
.sun-light s{
    top: auto;
    bottom: 0;
}

/* The actual way to get the rays */
   .sun-light:nth-child(3) {
    -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(90deg);
    -ie-transform:rotate(90deg);
    transform:rotate(90deg);
}

.sun-light:nth-child(1) {
    -webkit-transform:rotate(180deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(180deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(180deg);
    -ie-transform:rotate(180deg);
    transform:rotate(180deg);
}
.sun-light:nth-child(2) {
    -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(45deg);
    -ie-transform:rotate(45deg);
    transform:rotate(45deg);
}
.sun-light:nth-child(4) {
    -webkit-transform:rotate(135deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(135deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(135deg);
    -ie-transform:rotate(135deg);
    transform:rotate(135deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
This is the main object container.

  <div class="container_go">
    GO
  </div>

  <div class="sun-light">
    <b></b>
    <s></s>
  </div>
  <div class="sun-light">
    <b></b>
    <s></s>
  </div>
  <div class="sun-light">
    <b></b>
    <s></s>
  </div>
  <div class="sun-light">
    <b></b>
    <s></s>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have avoided `<div className="count-down__count">` for simplicity sake, but it can be accordingly stylized.